# La contraction « c'est » peut être après un sujet ?

Tags: grammaire

Je voudrais savoir si on peut mettre la contraction "c'est" après un sujet, par exemple:

> Mon amie c'est une grande personne

Selon moi, dans cette construction la phrase a deux sujets: "mon amie" et "ce". Je pense que c'est mieux: "mon amie est une grande personne".

J'ai l'impression que ça peut arriver dans langue parlée, mais je ne suis pas sûr.

Cette question est motivée par un ami qui n'utilise le verbe être qu'avec la contraction "c'est" dans une application de messagerie. Cela a lancé une discussion pour savoir si cette utilisation indiscriminée est correcte ou pas.

Comment: Cela permet mettre en avant le sujet. Une phrase courante : "Ma maman, c'est la meilleure [de toutes les mamans] !"

Answer (score 5):

La reprise du sujet avec « **c'est** »,  qui est l'abréviation du pronom neutre « **ce** » suivi du verbe être : « ***ce est*** », permet de mettre en relief ledit sujet. C'est une construction très courante en français qu'il est même parfois difficile d'éviter:

— **L'État, c'est moi !** ( <s>L'État est moi</s> ), attribué à Louis XIV.

— **Un an, c'est long** ! ( <s>Un an est long</s> ).

Contrairement à la reprise du sujet par un pronom non neutre, très fréquente à l'oral comme par exemple « **Mon père, il est cuisinier** » ou « **La reprise, elle est là !** » (François Hollande), elle n'est pas considérée comme incorrecte ou du moins comme l'indication d'un langage enfantin et/ou mal maîtrisé. Cela aurait été le cas avec :

— **Mon amie, elle est une grande personne**.

Attention, une virgule doit toujours séparer du reste de la phrase l'élément mis en emphase.

Answer (score 2):

On peut retrouver "c'est" après un sujet à l'oral effectivement, mais cela n'est pas le cas à l'écrit ; car "c'est" est la contraction de "cela" et "est", et "cela" se réfère ici au sujet donc on a affaire à un pléonasme grammatical, on répète deux fois le sujet en quelque sorte.